Different Page Layouts When Creating Account from Opportunity vs. Account Object
I’m encountering an issue with page layouts in Salesforce. When I create an account from an Opportunity record’s detail page, it shows me the page layout. However, if I go to the Account object and create a record using the New button, it shows the Lightning record page.
Why is there a difference in the page layouts, and how can I ensure consistency in the user experience?

Please [edit] your post to include important details, such as the custom button configuration, etc.
